# Rewrite Rule symbol explanation %^$

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I tried googling what they mean in the context of the rewrite rule in Apache but nothing is coming up as if it is implied knowledge, can some one please explain the meanings of these symbols?

examples

```
RewriteRule "^index\.html$"  "welcome.html"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [END]

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "(.*)"
RewriteRule "^/(.*)"       "/sites/%1/$1"
```

my guesses:

```
RewriteRule
^ = I am guessing it is the default root path of some sort? Or is it simply a starter for rewrite?
$ = Is this the ending to the first parameter for rewrite?
.* = [ "." = any single char, "*" = any length of whatever precedes it ] therefore any string
() = sets the regex as a backreference for $1
$1 = backreferences to the bracketed section of RewriteRule

RewriteCond
%{HTTP_HOST} = % is this an environmental variable identifier? if not, what is it and wouldnt {HTTP_HOST} be enough?
"(.*)" = A Rewrite Condition to anything kinda seems pointless..? But I got this from the Rewrite docs
%1 = A backreference to the RewriteCond, but which part? "%{HTTP_HOST}" or "(.*)", or maybe both results to the same?
```

Explanations of these archaic symbols would be very appreciated. Thanks again.

On a sidenote: I found it strange that most examples/explanations of Rewrite says to use allowoverride ALL on httpd.conf and then add the rules to .htaccess when the official docs say to NOT use allowoverride ALL and NOT use .htaccess if possible as it slows things down as it checks and compiles .htaccess everytime and to use httpd.conf instead as it compiles once and caches.

Comment: _"`(.*)` = A Rewrite Condition to anything kinda seems pointless..?"_ - not if the match is _captured_, to be used as a back reference later. _"%1 = A backreference to the RewriteCond, but which part?"_ - to the first part the expression captures. The wrapping in `(...)` is what does the capturing.

Comment: Apache httpd uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE). You can learn the basics of regular expressions in hardly 45 minutes. This is [the site I used](https://regexone.com/) to start learning regex, it all makes sense now. In any case, do not copy paste old Rewrite recipes, internet is filled with those copy pasted ill recipes which cause nothing more than trouble.